# How to build Taxonomy Menu with Parents and terms based on node?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

After prowling here and Google for a couple of weeks, and not finding the answer, I submit.

I need help assembling a Views-made block, in Drupal 7, that will display links to the pages of each term marked in the content node. I also need it to have a structure of:

Parent Term

- Term Link
- Term Link

Another Parent Term

- Term Link
- Term Link

So far, I cannot get the block to display any results, until I remove the Contextual Filters (that I read I'd need.) Does anyone have any guidance? I've installed/uninstalled, made/deleted more Views, Blocks, and Modules than I'd prefer to. I need for this one menu to take shape, before I can move ahead with development.

Comment: I Think You Want to implement your taxonomy terms as a menu tree..Am i right

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up having to do:

- create a new view of Taxonomy Terms, unsorted.
- Add Term: Name, & Vocab: Name as fields.
- Set format as HTML list, grouped by Vocab: Name.
- Add Taxonomy Term: Content with term relationship
- Add Content: Nid contextual filter

I then added a filter to exclude certain vocabularies, and finally, added a weight sorting for both term & vocab names.

Answer (score 1):

[Taxonomy Menu Module](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) will help you to create a menu block for a taxonomy vocabulary. You Will Need [Menu  Module](https://drupal.org/project/menu) however.

Steps

- Create a Menu By going to `Structure->Menu->` Add a Menu (test_menu), give it a title and and save.
- Now go to taxonomy and **edit the vocabulary** you want to transform to menu block.
- Under Description box , in **Taxonomy Menu Box** select the menu you want (here test_menu) from the **dropdown textfield** and save the vocabulary settings.
- Now you can use this menu block wherever you want.